# Meteor.Js: Use an async Meteor Method in Template

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

At my wits end.

The goal I'm trying to reach looks like this:

- Pass a url to the server from the client
- On the server, make an HTTP request to get the markup of said url
- Then find look for the corresponding url to the `og:image` property in the header

I can find the property I'm looking for on the server and `console.log` it but I'm having difficulty passing it to the client and then to the view. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
//-----------
//Client code
//-----------

Template.postShow.helpers({
  postImage: (url) ->
    Meteor.call "getRemoteImage", url, (err, result) ->
      if err
        // logs nothing
        console.log err
      else
        // logs nothing
        console.log result
        // sets nothing
        Session.set "myData", result
  theImage: () ->
    return Session.get "myData"
})


//------------
//Server Code:
//------------

function getArticleImage(url, callback){
  return Meteor.http.get(url, function(err, data){
        if (err){
          return err
        }
        else{

          $ = cheerio.load(data.content)
          imgURL = $("meta[property='og:image']").attr('content')
          //logs what I'm looking for
          console.log("server: ", imgURL)
          return imgURL
        }
      })
}

var getArticleImageSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(getArticleImage)

Meteor.methods({
  getRemoteImage: function(url){
    var result = getArticleImageSync(url)
    return result
  }
})


//--------------
// Template Code
//--------------

 <template name="postShow">
  <!-- the postImage function doesnt put anything in the view on it's own. it works in concert with the theImage function -->

  {{postImage url}}
  <p>{{theImage}}</p>

</template>
```

Comment: Where have you seen `Meteor.http.get`? It's probably from a very old tutorial, as that is an outdated API. I wouldn't recommend reading any Meteor tutorials written before the second half of 2014. [Here is the official documentation about HTTP requests in Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call). You should *not* need to do all that asynchronous stuff - on the server Meteor's `HTTP` API works synchronously.

Comment: Yep, you're totally right. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer this.